# Install Canon MX472 scanner on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, canon, scanner

I'm trying to install my multifunction printer on Ubuntu.
The printer is ok.
But can't make Ubuntu recognize the scanner.

I tried with xsane, but doesn't detect any devices

It's a wireless multifunction, anyone know how?

Comment: Nope. It's the first time I post this question

Comment: Sorry to have confused you. The duplicate state is not to indicate that you had asked this before but to help you getting a good answer by directing you to a previously asked question which already has concise answers. In case they did not help you you should [edit] you question to give us more details on what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use the [printer-](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100586902.html) and [scanner-driver](http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100587102.html) from cannon!

if you are searching on the cannon-site you only will find a MX477, but there are drivers for the whole [MX470-series](http://search-asia.canon-asia.com/canon__asia_en__asia_p_en/search.x?q=&ie=utf8&cat=0&ct=Support&pagemax=10&imgsize=1&pdf=ok&zoom=1&hf=category%09zubaken&cf=model_sm%3APIXMA+MX477&modelName=PIXMA+MX477&ref=support-asia.canon-asia.com&pid=xUfIbxSA3825YaZJJ770IQ..&qid=c8NFIlOGod-JZnpDOmWy5fzIsMpc2w4E&d=DOWNLOADS%09Linux).

if you don't know how to go on have a look at these instructions:
(notice: Linux Mint is based on Ubuntu)

- http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=165407
- http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=167625
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2128016

Comment: I've installed those drivers, but still not detecting the scanner.
By the way, I'm trying to connect to the scanner via wifi.

Comment: please test first, if it is at least working via USB. if it's not working test several USB-ports (with different controllers).